# How can I add a right click menu on chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I want to modify and stretch the default right-click menu pop-up on the chrome extension similar to the image below.
Here is the samp[image]le image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Content Menu API to get it displaying in the right-click menu.
the Google documentation breaks it down here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/user_interface/

This link is specifically the API you have access to that also allows for having it in the right click menu:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/

You can find the example they host on the documentation site specifically for the Context Menu example:  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/tutorials/focus-mode